# Using PowerShell to get the values of a SQL job schedule

Tags: sql, powershell

Currently, I am getting the job schedule for an existing SQL job and I want to get the values of how frequently it runs i.e. Daily, Weekly, Monthly, etc then I want to get when it should run next, and if the job runs on the weekends. I understand how to get all that information by doing

```
Get-SqlAgent -ServerInstance "$SERVER" | Get-SqlAgentJob $job | Get-SqlAgentJobSchedule | Format-List -Property *
```

This shows me all the relative information I need

```
Parent                     : Test_Job
ActiveEndDate              : 12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM
ActiveEndTimeOfDay         : 23:59:59
ActiveStartDate            : 3/4/2020 12:00:00 AM
ActiveStartTimeOfDay       : 00:00:00
DateCreated                : 3/4/2020 2:08:00 PM
FrequencyInterval          : 1
FrequencyRecurrenceFactor  : 0
FrequencyRelativeIntervals : First
FrequencySubDayInterval    : 2
FrequencySubDayTypes       : Hour
FrequencyTypes             : Daily
IsEnabled                  : True
JobCount                   : 1
```

I am looking at microsofts page on how to understand all the frequency information, but so far it seems like the only option is to have a bunch of nested IF statements that determine how often it runs. I can do it this way, but I figured there has to be a cleaner way to get the information I need. This is how I am currently parsing the information

```
if($frequency -eq "DAILY")
    {
        $MINUTES_LATEST_RUN_SUCCESS = "1500"
        #Code here to see how often it runs in a day

    }
    elseif($frequency -eq "WEEKLY")
    {
        $MINUTES_LATEST_RUN_SUCCESS = "11520"
        #Code here to see how how many days a week it runs

    }
    elseif($frequency -eq "MONTHLY")
    {
        $MINUTES_LATEST_RUN_SUCCESS = "50400"
       #Code here to see how which day it runs a month
    }
    else
    {
        $MINUTES_LATEST_RUN_SUCCESS = "1500"
    }
```

I figured this can't be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you get into many if/then statements, it's time to use a switch. There are sample code blocks in the PowerShell ISE (CRTL+J) and VSCode (CRTl+ALT+J) for this idea.

```
$a = 5
switch ($a) 
{ 
    1 {"The color is red."} 
    2 {"The color is blue."} 
    3 {"The color is green."} 
    4 {"The color is yellow."} 
    5 {"The color is orange."} 
    6 {"The color is purple."} 
    7 {"The color is pink."}
    8 {"The color is brown."}
    default {"The color could not be determined."}
}
```

Yours, but of course add your other code as needed in the block.

```
$frequency = 'DAILY'
switch ($frequency) 
{ 
    DAILY {"The job is run $frequency"} 
    WEEKLY {"The job is run $frequency"} 
    MONTHLY {"The job is run $frequency"} 
    default {$MINUTES_LATEST_RUN_SUCCESS = "1500"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I was also looking for documentation on the frequency interval, as there is no proper documentation on the Powershell pages, but came across this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysschedules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15